# How to delete lines containing a string in specific column

Tags: ruby

I have a big CSV file, and I need to delete all rows that contain a certain string (`"linux"`) in the fourth column. Could you advise me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
csv_lines = CSV.read('path/to/file.csv',headers:true).reject{|row| row[3].to_s.include?('linux') }
```